# Prove continuity for an integral function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity

Let $f$ a continuous real function defined on $[0,1]$ be given. It's asked to prove continuity in $x \in [0,1]$ for the function $$x \to \int_{0}^x \frac{f(t)}{(x-t)^{\frac{1}{2}}}dt$$ Thanks in advance for your answers!

Comment: This is very easy if you know Dominated Convergence Theorem.

Comment: I know that. I wrote the integrand function as $\frac{f(t)}{(x-1)^{\frac{1}{2}}} \chi_{[0,x]}$ but what dominant do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given function can also be written as $\int_0^{x}\frac  {f(x-s)} {\sqrt s} ds$ (by the substitution $t=x-s$). Let $x_n \to x$. Then $I_{(0,x_n)}(s) \frac  {f(x_n-s)} {\sqrt s}\to I_{(0,x)}(s) \frac  {f(x-s)} {\sqrt s} $ for every $s$ except $s=x$.  Also, $I_{(0,x_n)}(s) \frac  {f(x_n-s)} {\sqrt s}$ is dominated by $\frac M {\sqrt s}$ where $M=\sup \{|f(s)| :0\leq s \leq 1\}$. Since $\frac 1 {\sqrt s}$ is integrable on $[0,1]$ we can apply DCT to see that  the function is continuous.